# How to reduce API usage?

Tags: api

Got 100% API Usage, can you someone help me to reduce this percent.[image]

Comment: That would depend on what is making the requests.

Comment: How to find what call is taking the most space?

Comment: You can contact Salesforce support and they may increase the number of requests allowed. Would be good for you to find out what is consuming them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view a report of your last 7 days of API calls.

Steps to access folder:

1. Go to the **Reports** tab.
2. Search the folders for **Administrative
   Reports**
3. Here you will see a report titled **API Calls Made Within
   Last 7 Days**